# how to get an image based on a specific ID Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, frontend, backend

id like to render a image based on a specific id.

ive saved images into frontend > pages > pis folder. all named same as title in database.
fx) 1 image is named as "Indian food in the summer.jpg"
i have a table called meal in my database.

src="/pics/${meal.title}.jpg" is not working.
when refresh the server, it shows nothing.
when i put  src="/pics/${getMealWithId.title}.jpg",
it onlyshows alt="meal-pic".

would be appreciated if you could help me.

in database:

```
(id, title, maxNumberOfGuests, description, createdAt, price)
(1, "Indian food in the summer", 5, "A nice night out eating delicious indian food", "2019/12/7 14:34", 67)
```

code in meal.js (in frontend folder)

```
  window.handleMealRequest = async(params)=> {

     document.body.innerHTML =
     `<div>
          <img id="meal-pic" class="img-in-meals" src="/pics/${meal.title}.jpg" alt="meal-pic">
      </div>`

    const getMealResponse = await fetch(`/api/meals/${params.id}`);
    const getMeal = await getMealResponse.json();
    `<div class="meal-detail">${getMealWithId(getMeal)}</div>`;
}; 

function getMealWithId(mealFromDB) {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');

  mealFromDB.forEach(meal => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = Object.entries(meal);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
  })
};
```

Comment: Does putting `${meal.title}` in the `alt` show the correct text? Does requesting `http://domain.yours/pics/Indian food in the summer.jpg` work in a browser?

Comment: no, both dont work.